# Limit of lacunar power series at $1^-$

Tags: real-analysis, analytic-number-theory, limits-and-convergence, power-series, lacunary-series

I've asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4887391/limit-of-lacunar-power-series-in-1) question on MSE but I didn't get a convincive answer so I'm trying here. Here is the question :

Let $\sigma:\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow\mathbb{N}$ be strictly increasing, and consider the power series
$$ S_{\sigma}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^nx^{\sigma(n)}. $$
Can any real number in $[0,2]$ be obtained as the limit $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 1^-}S_{\sigma}(x)$ for some $\sigma$ ?

According to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2620319/702179) answer, the limit always is $\frac{1}{2}$ when $\sigma$ is a polynomial, WolframAlpha suggests that the limit is also $\frac{1}{2}$ with $\sigma(n)=n\log n$ (think of $\sigma(n)$ as the $n$-th prime number). Therefore my question can also be : Is the limit $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 1^-}S_{\sigma}(x)$ always $\frac{1}{2}$ ? if not, can any **rational** number in $[0,2]$ be obtained this way for some $\sigma$ ?

Note that the answer given on the original MSE post suggests that the series diverges at $x\to 1^-$ when $\sigma(n)$ diverges exponentially.

Comment: Example ... $$\lim_{x \to 1^-}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \big(x^{10k}-x^{10k+3}\big) = \frac{3}{10}$$Can you do others?

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Oh I see, so for your $\sigma$ adapted to $\frac{p}{q}$, then $\sigma$ is increasing only when $\frac{p}{q}\leqslant 1$, so it does not work when $\frac{p}{q}>1$, right ? And this also works when $\frac{p}{q}<0$, that seems strange to me.

Comment: There's an active bounty on the question at mathstack – seems like an odd time to post it here.

Comment: Since $\sigma$ is required to be strictly increasing, we cannot get negative limit.